# Suppress page number from Chapter side titlesec

Tags: header-footer, titlesec

I'm struggling with removing/suppressing the page number from pages with chapter headings.
When using `\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}` and

```
 \newpagestyle{mystylep}{ 
    \setfoot{}{}{}}
```

the page number on pages with only text is suppressed, but still appears on pages with chapter headings.. The pagestyle is used fro the Preface and Problem Description, right before the Abstract..

for the main text i use:

```
\newpagestyle{mystyle}{ 
    \sethead[][][\chaptertitle]{\chaptertitle}{}{} 
    \setheadrule{.4pt} 
    \setfoot{}{\thepage}{}}
```

and for the appendix:

```
\newpagestyle{mystylea}{ 
    \setfoot{}{\thepage}{}
```

I only like to take away the page number on pages with chapter heading in mystylep pages..

EDIT:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[block] 
    {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge} 
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt} 

%Main
\newpagestyle{mystyle}{ 
    \sethead[][][\chaptertitle]{\chaptertitle}{}{} 
    \setheadrule{.4pt} 
    \setfoot{}{\thepage}{}} 

%App
\newpagestyle{mystylea}{ 
    \setfoot{}{\thepage}{}} 

%Pre
\newpagestyle{mystylep}{ 
    \setfoot{}{}{}}
```

and:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,10pt,b5paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[lmargin=25mm,rmargin=25mm,tmargin=27mm,bmargin=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{alph}
\pagestyle{mystylep}
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{empty}
%\maketitle
\hypersetup{pageanchor=false}
\include{problem}
\include{abs}
\hypersetup{pageanchor=true}
\pagenumbering{roman}               
\pagestyle{mystyle}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\end{document}
```

problem.tex

```
\chapter*{Problem Description}

Text text text text text ..............

\vspace{1in}

\noindent
Assignment given: date
\\
Supervisor: NAME
```

abs.tex

```
\begin{abstract}
text text text text ........
\end{abstract}
```

Comment: The first page of a chapter is switch to the `plain` pagestyle, if I am not misremembering... So you could redefine that, or renew the chapter command to use a different pagestyle

Comment: I do that with `scrpage2` and it works fine (I know that's not an answer to the question, just a suggestion).

Comment: @Raphink I think `scrpage2` is an excellent suggestion, in general, although perhaps in this case the author has too much already invested in the `titlesec` definitions...

Comment: @Seamus Word!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is as easy as:

```
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{empty}
```

This is explained on page 7 (section 3.5) of the `titlesec` manual.

#### Edit

A quick fix for the actual problem seems to be to put `\thispagestyle{empty}` just after your `\chapter` command.

Comment: Seamus: have tried it before, and I don't know why, it does not work....

Comment: @latexmp try putting the above code _after_ your pagestyle definitions. Also, try making a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that): I can't reproduce your problem from the description you have given of it.

Comment: @Seamus I will try.

Comment: @Seamus If i can't suppress the numbers, any way I can make "Problem Description" have the same layout as the abstract without the use of \chapter* and make the "Preface" look the same without the use of \chapter* (same layout as Problem Description has now..)?

Comment: @latemp let me know if my edit helps...

Comment: \thispagestyle{empty} was a lifesaver!